# How to remove ini_set() a session is active in PHP 7.3.9?

Tags: php, session

[image]I am getting the Warning related ini_set() session is active. You cannot change the session module on xyz.php
Below is my code which i am using on xyz file

```
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max_age=0');
header('Expires: 0');
$_SESSION['nons']=rand(1,999999999);
$value=md5($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]." ".$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]." ".$_SESSION['nons']);
$_SESSION['xyz']=$value;
session_name('xyz');
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overriding the `php.ini` setting, you may manually setup the session cookie to be `httponly` with [session_set_cookie_params](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

```php
<?php

session_name('xyz');
// lifetime: 604800 = 1 week time, in seconds
// path:     '/' means all path in the domain can access the same cookie
// domain:   empty means accepting all domain
// secure:   FALSE means not necessary HTTPS
// httponly: TRUE so the session cookie is http only
session_set_cookie_params(604800, '/', '', FALSE, TRUE);
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();

header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max_age=0');
header('Expires: 0');

$_SESSION['nons']=rand(1,999999999);
$value=md5($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]." ".$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]." ".$_SESSION['nons']);
$_SESSION['xyz']=$value;
```

Comment: Is there any way to override ini settings? because now i cannot change the code

Comment: @SumitKundan: If you're using php through mod_php or filter, you may override the settings in your Apache config or .htaccess with the `php_value` directive. But that means you have to either have root permission or permission to upload file to the PHP code folder. And if you do, you may simply use my solution above.

Comment: I have uploaded the image of my phpinfo(). Please have a look mod_php is enabled so why this give me error and not override the settings

Comment: Some php.ini settings cannot be overrided by ini_set. Thats what the warning message said. You need to remove the ini_set call.